# ID3 algorithm - Which attribute to choose when I have the same gain for all attributes?

Tags: algorithm, data-mining

I have 3 attributes Temperature, Humidity and Wind? 
I am applying ID3 algorithm on the data about this attributes but I have the same information gain for all of them. Which attribute should I choose to continue the algorithm? Do I have to choose one arbitrary or I have to control all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another level and pick the one that gives maximum gain at the second level. If this results in a tie, try an additional level. I guess this means you have to try all.

Answer (score 0):

For each of them you will have the same gain and thus an arbitrary one will do. Just like selecting maximum element if there is a tie any of the ties is maximum.